# GKE move standard zonal cluster to auto pilot mode cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to move GKE standard zonal cluster to a new auto pilot mode cluster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment this operation is not possible.

In `GKE` Documentation [Autopilot overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview) under `Other limitations` you can find section [No conversion](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#no_conversion):

> Converting Standard clusters to Autopilot mode and converting Autopilot clusters to Standard mode is not supported.

Comment: quite odd this isn't a feature... yet